# The last table to update on the applyupdates

Tags: postgresql, delphi, database-connection, datasnap, tdatasetprovider

I have a CRUD that contains 5 tables and I need to do some processing on the server side alter the last table has been updated, the events on the datasetprovider happens after each individual table.

Like, I have 3 tables, person, car, personcar. I fill the fields I click save, first it's gonna save the person, then the car and last the personcar.
How can I know, in the transaction block, the last table?

I couldn't find the right 'after' event...

Comment: Have you looked into how e.g. TSqlResolver actually works, and what it produces, in terms of Sql statements sent to the server, to apply updates?

Answer (score 1):

there's no such built-in functionality unless you utilize nested datasets that is. you should either implement some specific remote method wrapping all required modifications or enhance midas with extra means (see for example "KT Data Components" lib to get the idea how this could be implemented)

Answer (score 0):

Your transaction should be on the serverside...have a method call that passes all your datasets in one call...handles the start/commit/rollback on the server side not the client side.